# How to decode hexadecimal number in IBM/360 column binary format

Tags: c#, binary, decode

I have a message:

```
x2400\x1100\x2001\x1020\x2100\x0900\x2008\x2012\x0900\x1001\x2001\x1010\x2001\x0900\x0802\x0812\x1200\x2010\x0802\x1004\x0820\x1010\x2100\x2002\x1012
```

It's in IBM column binary format. I read some documentation, but can't do by yourself.

https://www.masswerk.at/keypunch/?q=Mr.%20Donald%20F.%20Draper,%20104%20WAVERLY%20PLACE,%20APT%203R,%20NEW%20YORK,%20NY

Comment: Better to be asked at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will delete this comment after you reply. Can you please answer: did you encoded that code: 46f153285194qo6s31gv3kc71oj59513393q86i8 from your other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoded message is:

```
ALIMCTF(TRINITY'KEYPUNCH)
```

In order to decode the message, the following must be considered:

- Each character is identified by two bytes, e.g. `\x2400` corresponds to `A`.
- In a first step both bytes have to be decoded separately. For this purpose the *IBM/360 Column Binary format* (cbf) from the posted link (*Advanced Usage* section) has to be used. Each bit is assigned to a specific position, e.g. if byte 1 has the value `0x20`, then that corresponds to bit `5` and thus to position `Y`. Analogously for byte 2, e.g. if byte 2 has the value `0x12 = 0x10 + 0x02`, then this corresponds to bits `4` and `1` and thus to positions `5` and `8`. In total, this results in the positions `Y`, `5` and `8` or `Y58` for short.

  [image]
- In a second step, the character determined by the positions must be identified. To do this, the *IBM 029 keypunch* from the posted link (*Usage* section) must be used. E.g. the positions `Y`, `5` and `8` determine the character `(`.

  [image]

If this is done for the entire message, the following table results:

```
Message Byte1,  Byte2   Byte1,  Byte2,  Position    Character
        hex     hex     cbf     cbf                 IBM 029
\x2400  24      00      Y1      0       Y1          A                       
\x1100  11      00      X3      0       X3          L
\x2001  20      01      Y       9       Y9          I       
\x1020  10      20      X       4       X4          M           
\x2100  21      00      Y3      0       Y3          C
\x0900  09      00      03      0       03          T
\x2008  20      08      Y       6       Y6          F   
\x2012  20      12      Y       58      Y58         (
\x0900  09      00      03      0       03          T   
\x1001  10      01      X       9       X9          R
\x2001  20      01      Y       9       Y9          I
\x1010  10      10      X       5       X5          N
\x2001  20      01      Y       9       Y9          I
\x0900  09      00      03      0       03          T   
\x0802  08      02      0       8       08          Y
\x0812  08      12      0       58      58          '
\x1200  12      00      X2      0       X2          K
\x2010  20      10      Y       5       Y5          E
\x0802  08      02      0       8       08          Y
\x1004  10      04      X       7       X7          P
\x0820  08      20      0       4       04          U
\x1010  10      10      X       5       X5          N
\x2100  21      00      Y3      0       Y3          C
\x2002  20      02      Y       8       Y8          H       
\x1012  10      12      X       58      X58         )
```

where the decoded message is in the last column (read from top to bottom).